# Google geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-play, google-geocoder

I am using google Geocoder Javascript API for my Google store locator. Following is the javascript code I'm using for getting results from user input:

```
var searchValue = $('#searchValue').val(); //search input

var gg = new google.maps.Geocoder();
gg.geocode({'address': searchValue, 'componentRestrictions' : {country: 'XX'}}, function (data, status) {
  console.log(data);   //results data with the country name
  console.log(status);  // results OK
});
```

the above code results data with country name even though user enters junk value like 'sdfsdfdsf'

Problem is if user searches with the country name, its returning the same result as the value entered as junk values like 'asdfddv' or some wrong postal codes like '870'
How can I filter such results if user enters some junk values?
Is there a way to stop showing results if user enters junk values?

Answer (score 0):

The geocoding service tries to find the best possible match for your input. If it's not possible to find match for an address parameter it will search the best match for address components.

Please note that Google maps geocoding is not an address validation API, its purpose is resolving the input to the best matching coordinate.

I would suggest using a [places autocomplete widget](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) in conjunction with your search input to prevent the user from entering wrong addresses.

You can look at this example http://jsbin.com/zodayaz/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already implementing the Auto-complete input.  But, wanted to validate and handle these kind of errors.